# nativescript bottom nav that stays in place after loading new view

Tags: nativescript

I'm developing some app made on nativescript. Recently, i see that my app is more like website not an app, beacuse of how navigation works. 
I'm having bottom nav (atached - this grey with 5 icons) that is used to load proper views.
But when i click on home or any other icon, new view is loaded, but also nav is 'reloaded'. So it will not stay in place but load with new view. My question is - is possible oto have static botom bar ? I've tried 2 plugins found on marketplace, but without success. Thanks for and help.

[image]

```
<Page class="page" loaded="loaded" xmlns:header="components/header" xmlns:footer="components/footer">

<GridLayout rows="120,*,60">

    <StackLayout row="0">
        <!-- Common header -->
        <header:header/>
    </StackLayout>

    <ScrollView row="1" verticalAlignment="top" class="scrollview" tap="{{ loadPage }}">

        <StackLayout class="redeem">
            <Label text="Enter your code below to redeem your reward" class="info" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Code" class="info code" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <TextField  />
            <Button text="Redeem" class="button blue"></Button>

        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <StackLayout row="2">
        <!-- Common footer -->
        <footer:footer/>
    </StackLayout>

</GridLayout>

</Page>
```

:

```
<AbsoluteLayout class="footer" loaded="menu" horizontalAlignment="center" xmlns:sd="nativescript-ui-sidedrawer">
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*,*,*,*,*" horizontalAlignment="center">
    <Label row="0" col="0" class="fa" text="&#xf015;" tap="{{ mainPage }}"></Label>
    <Label row="0" col="1" class="fa" text="&#xf1f9;" tap="{{ creditPage }}"></Label>
    <Label row="0" col="2" class="fa" text="&#xf0fe;" tap="{{ seatPage }}"></Label>
    <Label row="0" col="3" class="fa" text="&#xf06b;" tap="{{ refs }}"></Label>
    <Label id="openMenu" row="0" col="4" class="fa" text="&#xf0c9;" tap="toggleDrawer"></Label>
    <!--<Label id="openMenu" row="0" col="4" class="fa" text="&#xf0c9;" tap="{{ loadPage }}"></Label>-->
</GridLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the nav to the outer component instead of the inner-view itself? (ie the home view)

Comment: Hi, Thank for interest. As you see, <footer> is just before GridLayout, and i dont ever seen that component may be outside of Page tag ?

Comment: im on about in your app.component code

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure what can help to understand your solution, so i'll add <footer> code - as update to my question.

Comment: you should have an app.component.html file? in the `app` folder

Comment: Sorry, i've never seen this 'app.component.html '. I'm  using {N} 3.4.1.

Comment: you should have an `app` folder, within that, you should have things like `app.component.html`, an `App_Resources` folder, a `main.ts`/`main.js` file, etc

Comment: Sorry, i've never seen those files. I can agree that basic {N} contains app.js, app.css and package.json.

Comment: I'm using plain Javascript app, without Typescript/Angular btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DockLayout` and dock the content to the bottom (Angular example [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/apod/apod.component.html#L19-L21))

Also in the upcoming release 4.0.0 of NativeScript (expected April-2018) will provide support for different root views (apart from `Page`) meaning you could create bottom static layout like `GridLayout` or even better a  bottom `TabView` (also coming for Android in 4.0.0) and create `Frame` in the upper layout for your dynamic content. (Look [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/5527))

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. What do you think, will ver 4.0 have breaking changes? I'm asking beacuse i have a dealine with project and i'm wondering if migration into {n} of existing project will be possible ?Cheers.

Comment: Version 4.0 is now live.. there are changes in the Frame API but they are extending the functionality via new `application.run` method - take a look in the following article updates https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/pull/1123 and https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/pull/1118

Comment: The documentation and the CHANGELOG.md will be soon udapted on live

Comment: Very good news then ! You are doing awesome job! Can i assume that i can try to update my existing 3.4 project into 4.0 ? Whats more, can you confirm that i'm unable to find any docs regarding new frame API that can help me with my issue (static bottom nav)? Thank You Nick !

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/e2e/modal-navigationuse this app as a reference.. for exmaple, look at this sample https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/e2e/modal-navigation/app/tab-root.xml#L1

Comment: or this one where Grid is used to place a Frame.. you can craete bottom row for the static toolbar content https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/e2e/modal-navigation/app/layout-root.xml#L1-L3

Comment: the main change when migrating from 3.4 to 4.0 is to change `application.start` with `application.run` and pass the app-root layout (any kind of layout like `StackLayout`, `TabView`, `Page` or directly a `Frame` navigating to a `Page` - each Frame should navigate to a Page element) - with this new feature now you can create top and bottom static toolbars, tabs, etc. and have multiple navigatable frames

Comment: this is very large improvement ! Cannot wait, what more {N} in version 4 will offer. Please don't stop doing this awesome job !!

Comment: there is no informations that 4.0 is released. https://www.nativescript.org/roadmap-and-releases#releases. When we can expect this info and also on blog?